# Do I owe any back taxes due to an IRS audit?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

I just got a call from someone claiming to be the IRS who threatened the police.
The number they used was 434-200-8555

Comment: I get these a couple times a year. The first time it can get your heart going, but usually you listen and notice that it is a computerized voice or somebody who can't provide specific details about your return or information. If you are ever in any doubt, hang up the phone and call the IRS directly. But 100% this is a scam, the IRS wouldn't get the police involved until they took you to court. You'll also notice that they want payment in some form of gift card or VISA card from somewhere like Walmart...

Answer (score 5):

This is a very common scam. Here is IRS link with more information:

https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-be-vigilant-against-phone-scams-annual-dirty-dozen-list-continues

Advice on what to do from the link:

> - Please report IRS or Treasury-related fraudulent calls to phishing@irs.gov (Subject: IRS Phone Scam).
> - Do not give out any information. Hang up immediately. The longer the con artist is engaged; the more opportunity he/she believes exists, potentially prompting more calls

Additional information on how to determine if this is fraud:

> The IRS will never:
>
> - Call to demand immediate payment using a specific payment method such as a prepaid debit card, gift card or wire transfer. Generally, the IRS will first mail a bill to any taxpayer who owes taxes.
> - Threaten to immediately bring in local police or other law-enforcement groups to have the taxpayer arrested for not paying.

To check with the **real IRS** whether you owe taxes:

> For those who owe taxes or think they do:
> Call the IRS at 800-829-1040. IRS workers can help.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is a scam. The IRS [does not call to demand money](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/dont-fall-for-scam-calls-and-emails-impersonating-irs), and will contact you by mail.

If you think you may owe the IRS, confirm by contacting them directly (by mail, by phone, in person) through legitimate channels.